# ZF2 - init or something that is called in every module controller

Tags: authentication, zend-framework2

I have a Module called "Backend" and in this module I want to check for valid authentication on all pages except the backend_login page. How do I do this? I tried to add it to the onBootstrap in the Backend/Module.php , but it turns out that is called in my other modules as well... which is of course not what I want.

So how do I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize does pretty much what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To get clear information about zf2 authentication you can follow:
[ZF2 authentication](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.authentication.intro.html)

- adapter auth
- database table auth
- LDAP auth
- digest auth....*These all are different methods here is an example of database table auth:*
  in every controller's action, where you need user auth  something should like this:

  ```
  use Zend\Authentication\Result;
  use Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService;
  use Zend\Authentication\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
  use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter as DbAdapter;
  use Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable as AuthAdapter;

  public function login($credential)
  {   
     $bcrypt = new Bcrypt();
     $user   = new User();
     $auth = new AuthenticationService();

     $user->exchangeArray($credential);

     $password    = $user->password;
     $data        = $this->getUserTable()->selectUser($user->username);

     if (!$data){
      $message = 'Username or password is not correct!';
     } 
     elseif($auth->getIdentity() == $user->username){
       $message = 'You have already logged in';
     }
     elseif($bcrypt->verify($password, $data->password)){

          $sm          = $this->getServiceLocator();
          $dbAdapter   = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
          $authAdapter = new AuthAdapter(
                  $dbAdapter,
                  'user',
                  'username',
                  'password'
          );
          $authAdapter -> setIdentity($user->username) -> setCredential($data->password);

          $result = $auth->authenticate($authAdapter);

          $message = "Login succesfull.Welcome ".$result->getIdentity();


      } else {
          $message =  'Username or password is not correct';
      }


  return new ViewModel(array("message" =>$message));
  }
  ```

  **Like this in every action you can check whether it is authenticated or not**

  ```
  if($auth -> hasIdentity()){

          //your stuff
  }
  else{
          //redirected to your login route;
      }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I had once a similar problem and figured it out within my Module.php in the `onBootstrap()` function. Try this, it worked for me:

```php
class Module {
  // white list to access with being non-authenticated
      //the list may contain action names, controller names as well as route names
  protected $whitelist = array('login');

     //....

  public function onBootstrap($e){
    $app = $e->getApplication();
    $em  = $app->getEventManager();
    $sm  = $app->getServiceManager();

    $list = $this->whitelist;
    $auth = new AuthenticationService();

    $em->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, function($e) use ($list, $auth) {
      $match = $e->getRouteMatch();

      // No route match, this is a 404
      if (!$match instanceof RouteMatch) {
        return;
      }

      // Route is whitelisted
       $action = $match->getParam('action');
      if (in_array($action, $list) ) {
        return;
      }

      // User is authenticated
        if ($auth->hasIdentity()){
          return;
        }

      // the user isn't authenticated
      // redirect to the user login page, as an example
      $router   = $e->getRouter();
      $url      = $router->assemble(array(
          'controller' => 'auth',
          'action'=>'login'
              
      ), array(
        'name' => 'route_name',
          
      ));

      $response = $e->getResponse();
      $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Location', $url);
      $response->setStatusCode(302);

      return $response;
    }, -100);
  }
}
```

Or you may see [bjyauthorize](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize).